# ModuleNotFoundError in python (spyder project)

Tags: python, module, package, importerror

**1. The environment**

I am working in Windows 10 with Anaconda/Spyder tools.
I have a python project organized as follow.

```
folder_project
  test_all.py
  folder_utils
     __init__.py
     function1.py
  folder_tests
     __init__.py
     test_function1.py
```

The **init**.py files are empty files.
Basic idea for implementing code coverage of my code (maybe methodology can be improved) is that I will have:

- one python file to test in different manners one function
- test_function1.py will contain one function per test:

  def test_001():
      ...
- test_all.py file will call all functions for all test_functionXXX.py files

In Spyder, I have taken care to add in PYTHONPATH the folder_project.

**2. The problem**

I encounter error in importing the folder_tests package...

I have in test_all.py

```
import folder_tests.test_function1
def main():
   # Testing function1
   test_function1.test001()
```

And I get following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_tests.test_function1'
```

If I only do

```
import folder_tests
```

I have no error message, but then I can do nothing with that...

If I change the import statement in

```
from folder_tests import test_function1
```

I get following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'test_function1' from 'folder_tests'
```

Please, any idea how I could correct that?

I thank you in advance for your help!

Bests,

Pierrot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The origin of the error doesn't seem related to python, but spyder.
I stopped and re-launched spyder, it didn't work, I simplified name of files, and it worked, and I then re-used the previous file names, and it still works...
Kind of a headache here...

Sorry for the bother.

Bests,

Pierrot

Answer (score 0):

Pierrot, regarding your answer I agree, it is a total headache but I got to the bottom of the issue for 2 scenarios:

1. If the folders which you referenced are not housed in a folder that is recognized by Spyder as a project folder then this issue occurs. In your case this would be *folder_project*. This can be tested by going to *Projects->Open Project* if the folder you select is not recognized as a project folder it will tell you, and not open it. Can be fixed by *Project->New Project->Existing Directory*
2. Folder name the same as file name (Spyder specific, not an issue using other IDEs such as pycharm)
   I had the folder name the same as the file name e.g. folder called 'email' and file inside called 'email.py'. When I tried to import, it raised 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email'.

Here's the version that failed with matching file and folder name:

```
import email.email as e
```

Here's the version that worked with differentiated file (added and 's') and folder name:

```
import emails.email as e
```